# Checking the validity of a date

Tags: java, date

If I am given some random date, then I need to check if that date really exists or not and then display `true` or `false`. I need to return `false` for both the dates `32-11-2010` and  `31-02-2010` because the month of february doesn't contain 31st. How do we do this in Java?

Comment: @acm There's great answers on both questions; one is probably a duplicate of the other, but I've raised a flag and requested that that one just be fully merged into this one.