# JVM does not respond when user clicks button 1/2, it just becomes stuck

Tags: java, arrays, swing, user-interface, actionevent

[image]

I am trying to make a program that user is able to enter a date like: `28 -03 - 2014`.

This and the program reads that, gives the date of tomorrow like: `29 - march - 2014`.
The program must check about:

- String max 10.
- date of day(2 digit): 1 - 31
- String: `-`
- month (two digit): 1 - 12
- String: `-`
- year : four digits

Here is my code!

```
    public String month()
    {
            int month = 0;
            switch(month){
            case 1 :monthString = " Janauri";
                    break;
             case 2: monthString = "February"
    .......
    ublic String dateOfTomorrow(int day, int month, int year)

    {
    String Date =  day+ "-" + month+ "- " + year;
    day++;
    if(day > totalDaysInMonth(month));
    {// new  month
    day = 1;
    month++;
    if(month > 12)
    {//new year
    month= 1;
    year ++;
    }
  }
    return Date;

    }
        private boolean  totalDaysInMonth(int day)
        {
            if( day >= 1 && day < 31)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
                }
        }


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
            for ( int i = 1; i<31;);
                String s = tf.getText();
                if ( e.getSource() == b1)
                {

                    l2.setText(s);

                }
                else if (e.getSource ()== b2)
                {
                    l2.setText(monthString);
                }

            }
```

Comment: Use a `JSpinner` with a [`SpinnerDateModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerDateModel.html) instead.  **Tips:**  1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). 2) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: *"when i click button 1/2 it just stack."*  If by 'stack' you mean the application causes a stack trace, then..  Always copy/paste error & exception output.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I'm guessing that he's misspelling "stuck", that he's completely new to spelling as well as to Java.

Comment: Sorry for spelling mistakes.  I mean stuck.  Can't take action n I can either close the program.

Comment: Did you try fixing your code as per user2275785's suggestion in his answer below?

Comment: I did but still is not working correctly. The user is still able to type a date like this: 44- 15 - 2014.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is in this loop:

```
for ( int i = 1; i<31;);
```

which will never end.
Remove that empty loop or change it to:

```
for ( int i = 1; i<31;i++);
```

Comment: Thanx man. I did work but still got some issues . Like date is 40-13-2014. Which is not a correct date.

Comment: [Checking the validity of a date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528047/checking-the-validity-of-a-date)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you mean by 1/2 stack. But if you make a string of some variables

```
String Date =  day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
```

and then change the variables it doesn't have any effect on the string.
So you will still get the same date back.

And a tip for better readability makes your variables camel cased. So instead of Date call it date.

Comment: I meant if I click on button 1 or 2 , it doesn't response. It just stuck . No reaction .

Comment: Do you attach a event listener to the button? because otherwise the button is very useless.

Comment: yeah it has event listener. that problem is solved now. it was because of the loop never ends. for ( int i = 1; i<31;); but still got issues with invalid date like 54-30-2014.